# Is there a way to switch users from the new lock screen?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

I upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10 and I'm having a couple issues with the lock behavior (ctrl+alt+l).

In 13.10 the monitor would go into power save and then when the screen turned back on I was able to switch users.

In 14.04, the monitor stays on and there doesn't appear to be a way to switch users without the user that locked it logging in and the logging out.

Is there a way to switch users from the new lock screen? Is there a way to turn the screen off upon locking?

Comment: By power save, do you mean suspending your machine?

Comment: I think it's the same as "turn screen off" in the lock settings

Comment: No, turning the screen off and suspending are different.

Comment: What I meant by power save was "turn screen off" not suspend

Comment: So is it fine if ctrl + alt + l turns the screen off?

Answer (score 6):

I found a way which I will need to explain to my little kids who did not figure it out...  Click on the top right corner and you will see the list of users.

Honestly, I do not like it because it is not obvious and not user friendly. Before my 6 years old and my 9 years old could figure it out by herself, now I will need to explain it....

Comment: Ah yes I found it, but often for some reason I cannot click the gear icon. It shows up, but when I click it nothing happens. I then have to ctrl-alt-del and choose logout before I can switch.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, but when I first upgraded to 14.04 I had this problem fairly often.