# Switch user after upgrade to 14.04 not working

Tags: login, switch-user

i did an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.
Now the switch user option does not work any more.
the logged in user has to log out before any other user can log in.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Peter

Comment: Is this on the panel menu or from the lock screen? For the latter see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453765/is-there-a-way-to-switch-users-from-the-new-lock-screen

Comment: Hi Takkat, the switching user works neither from the panel nor from the lock screen. Just nothing happens if i click on the switch account or a another specific user. :-(

Comment: weird... it works as expected on all my 14.04 machines here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was the display manager. I previously had "gdm" and solved my problem by switching to "lightdm" Display Manager.

Run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

In my case I had "gdm" selected and I selected "lightdm" instead. Reboot and login again. Now, account switching should work both while logged in and from the lock screen.

Potentially you need to install lightdm.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

My machine was initially installed as a 12.04 server, and then I added Unity and finally upgraded to 14.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, both users must be running the same display manager. This is true on my machine that has multiple DMs available.